# How to get the edge list of a strongly connected components in a graph?

Tags: r, algorithm, graph, cycle, igraph

I have a weighted directed multigraph with a few cycles. With `clusters` function in `igraph` package, I can get the nodes belongs to a strongly connected components. But I need the path/order of the nodes that form a cycle.

**EDIT** after @josilber's response

I have a very dense graph, with 30 nodes and around 2000 edges. So `graph.get.subisomorphisms.vf2` takes too long to run in my case.

I'm not familiar with graph algorithm, but I'm thinking maybe do a DFS to the original or reverse graph and use the `order` or `order.out` might work, but not sure.

Or any other ideas to make this run faster are welcomed!

Example

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(123)
graph <-graph(c(1,2,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,8,10,9,10,9,10,10,11,10,5,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,14,20,15,16, 16,17,17,18,18,19,19,20,20,21,21,1,22,23,22,23,23,22),directed=T)
E(graph)$weight= runif(ecount(graph),0,10)

> clusters(graph, "strong")
$membership
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1

$csize
[1]  2 21

$no
[1] 2
```

How do I get the edge list of a cycle with the highest weight here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all nodes in each strongly connected component form a cycle and that you're only interested in this large cycle (e.g. in your example you're just interested in the cycle with nodes 1:21 and the cycle with nodes 22:23), then you can extract the node order that forms the cycle, grab the weights on the edges, and compute the total weight of the cycle.

```
# Compute the node order of the cycle for each component by performing an
# isomorphism with a same-sized directed ring graph
clusts <- clusters(graph, "strong")
(cycles <- lapply(1:clusts$no, function(x) {
  sg <- induced.subgraph(graph, clusts$membership == x)
  n <- sum(clusts$membership == x)
  col <- rep(c(1, 0), c(1, n-1))  # Used to grab isomorphism starting at 1
  sg.idx <- graph.get.subisomorphisms.vf2(sg, graph.ring(n, directed=TRUE), col, col)[[1]]
  which(clusts$membership == x)[sg.idx]
}))
# [[1]]
# [1] 22 23
# 
# [[2]]
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

Now you can grab the sum of the edge weights for each cycle:

```
sapply(cycles, function(x) sum(graph[from=x, to=c(tail(x, -1), x[1])]))
# [1]   8.833018 129.959437
```

Note that this is in general NP-hard, because finding a Hamiltonian cycle in a general graph is NP-hard. Therefore the `graph.get.subisomorphisms.vf2` call could be quite slow for large graphs.

Comment: Thanks for your help! My graph is quite dense, so it did takes a while to run... I'm wondering is a dfs search on a subgraph would get the correct node order in a cycle. I'm not very familiar with isomorphism or graph theory. Pardon me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @qshngv As I said in my post, in general finding a cycle is NP-hard, meaning the runtime will increase exponentially as the problem size increases. Further, dense graphs will have an asymptotically exponential number of cycles returned. Therefore it is not surprising that this approach (or any other) would have a long runtime for a large, dense graph.

Comment: Also, since I have a multigraph, how do I identify which edge to form the max weighted cycle? Since each edge in my graph represents a point, and I need to identify the specify point for some purpose. Much appreciated for your time!

Comment: @qshngv if you connect a and b in a cycle, it would always select the maximum-weight edge connecting a and b. Therefore you could remove all other a -> b edges before running the procedure.

Comment: Hi, sorry fro the delayed follow up, so I tried to run the code, and got the following error. `Error in graph.get.subisomorphisms.vf2(sg, graph.ring(n, directed = TRUE),  : 
  subscript out of bounds`,  **dput(clusts) is** `structure(list(membership = c(1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 9, 8, 10, 4, 5), csize = c(3, 
1, 17, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), no = 10L), .Names = c("membership", 
"csize", "no"))`, seems like the `graph.get.subisomorphisms.vf2` returned an empty list. I'm not sure why is this?