# how to find path of a cycle from an adjacency list

Tags: r, algorithm, graph

I have a directed subgraph with all the nodes in a cycle (with 21 nodes and ~250 edges) and I want to know the order of how the nodes form the cycle.

I'm not familiar with graph algorithm. I thought about using the `igraph::graph.dfs` function to the original or reverse graph. And use the `order` or `order.out` returned as the order, but it didn't work.

The subgraph was a strongly connected components found with `igraph::clusters`

I've asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217411/how-to-get-the-edge-list-of-a-strongly-connected-components-in-a-graph) but the `graph.get.subisomorphisms.vf2` takes too long to run in my case.

I'm thinking if I can get an ordered adjacency list like this, I may able to find the cycle starting from the longest list

[image]

But I can only get an unordered list using `igraph::get.adjlist`, I'd like to know if there's a way to get an ordered list like below.

And any suggestions to find the node order of the cycle?

Thanks in advance!

data

```
> dput(adjlist)
structure(list(`26` = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 15, 16, 
18, 19), `2` = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 15, 16, 18), `30` = c(1, 
2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21), `25` = c(1, 
2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 18, 21), `29` = c(1, 2, 
3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 18, 21), `9` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 7, 8, 10, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19), `27` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
8, 14, 15, 18), `13` = c(3, 4, 5, 15), `14` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21), `8` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 15, 16, 18), `23` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
10, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19), `20` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21), `19` = c(1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21), 
    `17` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
    21), `12` = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 8), `24` = c(4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
    11, 15), `21` = c(13, 14), `6` = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 
    15), `28` = c(1, 7, 11, 16), `15` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
    8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21), `11` = c(3, 4, 
    5, 6, 8, 15)), .Names = c("26", "2", "30", "25", "29", "9", 
"27", "13", "14", "8", "23", "20", "19", "17", "12", "24", "21", 
"6", "28", "15", "11"))
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. You say your graph is a subgraph of a cycle - then it either is a cycle and has exactly as many edges as it has nodes, or it isn't a cycle if some edges are missing. Both seem not to be the case since you have more edges than nodes. Do you mean that there is a cycle in your graph that contains all nodes, and you want to find that? If so, this is the Hamiltonian Cycle problem and is NP-hard assuming you can visit each node only once, so no luck with an efficient algorithm so far.

Comment: If you can visit nodes more often, then an efficient solution exists; you basically modify a strongly connected components algorithm to remember the edges via which it detects cycles, then you get a collection of cycles and just have to do a Eulerian Cycle of the subgraph spanned by those cycles.

Comment: Hi, sorry about the confusion. It's a subgraph formed with all nodes in a cycle. So all edges are preserved. I've edited it in the post. That sounds like a solution. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: So you are allowed to revisit nodes then?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm not clear of what revisit nodes means. I want to get a cycle that each node has the same number of in degree and out degree. I guess it could be revisit, but the simplest way is like a circle with same number of nodes as edge. I hope I explained my situation. Thanks...

Comment: I'll be posting an answer shortly, this shouldn't be in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure the problem is correctly understood: you have a subgraph of a directed graph induced by the vertices of a strongly connected component. What you would like to have is a cycle containing all vertices of the component. Two possible versions (see [the introductory paragraphs here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28graph_theory%29) for some clarification on the confusing terminology that has developed in this respect):

a) Each vertex is allowed to appear exactly once on the cycle, i.e. you want a simple cycle where each vertex is incident with exactly two edges of the cycle. Finding such a cycle is the [Hamiltonian Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) problem, a staple of complexity theory which is NP-hard; no human is known to have an efficient algorithm for that.

b) Vertices are allowed to be adjacent to more than two edges of the cycle, i.e. you want a closed walk through the component. You can do that by identifying cycles that connect the component (you should be able to extract those easily enough from an algorithm that identifies strongly connected components), and then you build a [Eulerian Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) of the union of the cycles you found, ignoring all other edges in the component. This is possible efficiently, and should be fairly straightforward to implement.